# Using StreamReader to Read lines of user names and place in a shell

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The following is what I have that is exporting all usernames to a text file.

```
de.Path = "WinNT://domain.domain.com"
    'Write each user to a text file as List
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        MsgBox("Writing all Users to Memory, Click OK and wait for Window to Close")
        For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children()
            sw.WriteLine(d.Name)
        Next
        Console.Clear()
    End Using
```

Once this is done I would like to run this command on each and get the text exported

```
  services.msc /computer=(INSERT NEXT ENTRY IN TEXT FILE)
```

The exporting part I can handle, but I am stuck with how to have the program read each line and then run the command on each line.
I am assuming I need to use streamreader in a way like this?

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.Open))

        End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ServiceContoller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class to connect to the service controller on each of the returned computers, instead of using services.msc.

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.Open))

   Dim InstalledServices as List(of String) = GetInstalledServices(sr.ReadLine.Trim)

End Using


Function GetInstalledServices(ByVal Computer As String) As List(Of String)

   ' Do your service controller work here ....

End Function
```

*EDIT:* You could use [Process.GetProcesses(Computer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8b2hzk8%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get the running processes on a remote machine.

Comment: Is there a ProcessController class I can use instead of servicecontroller?

Comment: Thanks for the tips ProcessController is more of What I am after